# Group by min of date in pandas dataframe, returning nanoseconds not days

Tags: python, date, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to group entries of the column 'Client Name' by the minimum date a corresponding cell.

```
Client Name     Recency
A               -10 days
B               -4 days
C               -1 days
A               -5 days
B               -2 days
C                0 days
```

So the final result should be is

```
A               -5
B               -2
C                0
```

When I check the type of my 'recency' I get:

```
>> df['recency'].dtype
dtype('<m8[ns]')
```

Which I think is my problem as my days are in nanoseconds? But I find that odd because it says days in the column.

However when I do the grouping:

```
>> df.groupby(['Client Name'], sort=False)['recency'].min()
A                          -73785600000000000
B                          -345600000000000
C                           0
```

Which leads me to believe I am subtracting nanoseconds and not days.

Why would the column of the dataframe change to nanoseconds? How do I return the min of the days rather than the nanoseconds?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I try your test dataframe and [`min`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.min.html) values are different as you - maybe you are using [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html).

You can try change [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with subset `df[['Recency','Client Name']]`:

```
print df
  Client Name  Recency
0           A -10 days
1           B  -4 days
2           C  -1 days
3           A  -5 days
4           B  -2 days
5           C   0 days

print df[['Recency','Client Name']].groupby(['Client Name'], sort=False).min()
             Recency
Client Name         
A           -10 days
B            -4 days
C            -1 days
```

If you need remove text `days`, convert `timedelta` to `int`:

```
df['RecencyNo'] = (df['Recency'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).astype(int)
print df
  Client Name  Recency  RecencyNo
0           A -10 days        -10
1           B  -4 days         -4
2           C  -1 days         -1
3           A  -5 days         -5
4           B  -2 days         -2
5           C   0 days          0

print df.groupby(['Client Name'], sort=False)['RecencyNo'].min()
Client Name
A   -10
B    -4
C    -1
Name: RecencyNo, dtype: int32
```

EDIT:

You can check [`issue 5724`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5724) - maybe it is bug.